# How can I expand a string to r-markdown code?

Tags: r-markdown

Using r-markdown and Ryacas, I often want to display a yacas expression as an inline equation.  E.g.

> ```{r}
> x <- ysym("a^2 + b^2");
> ```
> $`r yac_str(x)`$

Since I do this so often, I'd like to find a more succinct way to express the inline equation command, something like

> fn(x)

Is there any way to define a macro that will do this in r-markdown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An **r-markdown snippet** provides a way to do this.

See

https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-anything-like-a-macro-in-r-markdown/76406

for details.